# Why does $I_x(a,\frac{1}{2})$ behave like $e^{-a}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-function, beta-function

I am interested in the behavior of the regularized incomplete beta function $I_x(a,\frac{1}{2})$. Graphing on WolframAlpha, I noticed that it behaves similarly to $e^{-ka}$ in the sense that $x\to1$ behaves like $k\to0$.

Here's a [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu2BB.png) showing one instance of the similarity. Where does this relationship come from? Why does $I_x(a,\frac{1}{2})$ act like an exponential decay function? And what is the relationship between $x$ and $k$?

I tried checking out some of the representations of $I$ [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17), but I couldn't figure it out. Any answers would be highly appreciated - thanks a lot!

Edit: Here is a Mathematica Manipulate command which explores this relationship:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{BetaRegularized[x, (n-1)/2, 1/2], Exp[-(1-x)n]}, {n, 2, 10}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: This is mere coincidence. The power series expansion of the incomplete beta function is only vaguely similar to the exponential.

Comment: Laplace's method gives
$$\int_0^x t^{-1} (1 - t)^{-1/2} e^{a \ln t} dt \sim
t^{-1} (1 - t)^{-1/2} \bigg\rvert_{t = x}
 \int_{-\infty}^x e^{a (\ln x + \ln'(x) (t - x))} dt, \\
I_x {\left( a, \frac 1 2 \right)} \sim
\frac {x^a} {\sqrt {\pi (1 - x) a}},
\quad a \to \infty,$$
so $k = -\ln x$.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim! If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.